# Show that the fundamental solution $E_2$ of Laplace equation is local integrable

Tags: integration, proof-verification

> > For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ the function
> >     $$
> > E_n(x):=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert}\right), & \text{ for }n=2\\\frac{1}{(n-2)\sigma_n}\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{n-2}}, & \text{ for }n>2\end{cases}
> > $$
> >     is called *fundamental solution* ofthe Laplace equation. Show that the fundamental solution $E_2$ is local integrable in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Hello!

If I got it right, I have to show that for all compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ it is 
$$
E_2\in L^1(K)=\left\{f\colon K\to\mathbb{R}: f\text{ is measurable }, \int_K\lvert f(x)\rvert\, d\mu(x)<\infty\right\}
$$

**ad (1)**:

Consider any compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

$K$ - as a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ - is bounded, i.e. $\exists C>0$ so that $\lVert x\rVert\leq C$ for all $x\in K$.

$$
\int_K\left\lvert\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert}\right)\right\rvert\, dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_K \lvert\ln(1)-\ln(\lVert x\rVert)\rvert\, dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_K\ln(\lVert x\rVert)\, dx\\\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_K\ln(C)\, dx=\underbrace{\frac{\ln(C)}{2\pi}}_{=:D<\infty}\int_K\, dx\\=D\cdot\underbrace{\mu(K)}_{<\infty}<\infty
$$

Because the Lebesgue-measure $\mu$ of a compact set is finite, right?

How can I show that $E_2\colon K\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just follows from radial coordinates. We take $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. Then you need to integrate

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int_{0}^{R}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(r)rdrd\theta$$
Use the fact that $\int \ln(r)r=\frac{1}{2}\ln (r) r^{2}-\frac{1}{4}r^{2}$, the above integral is just $\frac{R^{2}}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(R)R^{2}$. Note that your formula for the fundamental equation in $n=2$ has a typo. Off the original we had no singularity and the function is clearly locally integrable.

Comment: There is no typo, we defined it that way. So my calculation is... wrong? I did not use radial coordiantes...

Comment: What is your $R$?

Comment: There is typo, because the fundamental solution is $-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|x|)$, not $\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(1/|x|)$. Here $R>0$ is any constant to check if it is locally integrable around $0$.

Comment: But we defined itthat way and the professor said: Maybe others define it in another way... is is R from the fact, that K is bounded? because for all $x\in K$ it is $\lVert x\rVert\leq R$ for a R>0?

Comment: @math12: I think your professor's definition is okay because $\ln(1/|x|)=-\ln(|x|)$. So the two definition is the same. I just use a ball of radius $R$ to form a small enough neighborhood. You can think as $K\subset B_{R}$.

Comment: ah okay, because K is compact tehre always is a ball containing K. And then if the integral over the ball is finit the integral of K is finit as well because of the monotony of the integral, right? what is with the measurability of $E_2$? because i think i have to show that, too when I have to show that $E_2$\in L^1(K)$?

Comment: @math12: I think if you are working with PDE, you should know $x,|x|,\ln(|x|),-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|x|)$ are all measurable functions. We are proving the fundamental equation is locally integrable around $0$. Locally integrable at other points is trivial because the function is continuous there.

Comment: And one last question: why do you have the minus in your calculation? the integrand is $\lvert -\ln(x)\rvert$ right?

Comment: I think your result is not right, because the inner integral is $\int_0^R\lvert\ln(r)\rvert r\, dr$ and to my opinion this has to be divided into two parts: $\int_0^1 -\ln(r)r\, dt+\int_1^R\ln(r) r\, dt$, getting another result as yours.

Comment: Moreover it is not that clear, that §E_2\colon K\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is masurable...

Comment: @math12: The integrand is not $|-\ln(x)|$. It is $-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|x|)$.

Comment: I have to show the integrability, right? And to show that a function is integrable one has to show that $\int\lvert f(x)\rvert\, dx <\infty$, or?

Comment: @math12: I see you mean you need $\int_{\Omega}|f(x)|dx<\infty$. But at here we choose $R$ small enough, so this is not an issue. Mind that $\ln(r)<0$ for $r<1$, so the minus sign actually turned it positive.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see your point! ;(

Comment: Why is it enough to check if it is locally integrable around 0? I do not understand. K can be any compact subset...

Comment: @math12: Locally integrable means locally integrable at a small enough neighborhood around every point. Here the only singularity of $\ln(|x|)$ is at $x=0$. At other points since it is continuous it must have a maximum $M$ in the neighborhood ball. So the integral is bounded by $m^{*}(B_{R})M$.

Comment: No, locally integrable means: integrable on each compactum. So I do not see why you can chose the compactum around 0 as small as you want, because that has to be integrable on every compactum around 0.

Comment: @math12: This is not the usual definition (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LocallyIntegrable.html) I learned from Friedlander and Joshi. But I think in our case is equivalent.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function

Comment: By the way: The function is only defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. I do not understand why then it is asked if it is locally integrable on whole $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @math12: Yes, I think the wikipedia definition is the "unusual" one. I think the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ if you allow extended real values including infinity. But you may think of it as improper integral in Riemann sense.